# Sqlite3 "chained" query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I need to create a configuration file from a data file that looks as follows:

```
MAN1_TIME '01-JAN-2010 00:00:00.0000 UTC'
MAN1_RX 123.45
MAN1_RY 123.45
MAN1_RZ 123.45
MAN1_NEXT 'MAN2'
MAN2_TIME '01-MAR-2010 00:00:00.0000 UTC'
MAN2_RX 123.45
[...]
MAN2_NEXT 'MANX'
[...]
MANX_TIME [...]
```

This file describes different "legs" of a trajectory. In this case, `MAN1` is chained to `MAN2`, and `MAN2` to `MANX`. In the original file, the chains are not as obvious (i.e., they are non-sequential).

I've managed to read the file and store in an **Sqlite3** database (I'm using the Python interface). The table is stored with three columns: `Id`, `Par`, and `Val`; for instance, `Id='MAN1'`, `Par='RX'`, and `Val='123.45'`.

I'm interested in querying such database for obtaining the information related to 'n' legs. In English, that would be:

```
"Select RX,RY,RZ for the next five legs starting on MAN1"
```

So the query would go to `MAN1`, retrieve `RX`, `RY`, `RZ`, then read the parameter `NEXT` and go to that `Id`, retrieve `RX`, `RY`, `RZ`; read the parameter `NEXT`; go to that one ... like this five times.

How can I pass such query with "dynamic parameters"?

Thank you.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a hierarchical query to me.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: +1: I looked for "Hierarchical" queries and it seems that, indeed, that's what I am looking at. Now ... how do I go about this :) I'm documenting myself in the mean time...

Comment: Dare I ask, but do you absolutely have to use SQLite?  Oracle and SQL Server have free versions, both of which have hierarchical query syntax.

Comment: I do. I cannot install any server-dependent database in our network.

Comment: Can you do some processing for that data file and then create different kind of database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question in the [SQLAlchemy website](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#relationship-configuration). From the documentation:

> The adjacency list pattern is a common
>   relational pattern whereby a table
>   contains a foreign key reference to
>   itself. This is the most common and
>   simple way to represent hierarchical
>   data in flat tables. The other way is
>   the “nested sets” model, sometimes
>   called “modified preorder”. Despite
>   what many online articles say about
>   modified preorder, the adjacency list
>   model is probably the most appropriate
>   pattern for the large majority of
>   hierarchical storage needs, for
>   reasons of concurrency, reduced
>   complexity, and that modified preorder
>   has little advantage over an
>   application which can fully load
>   subtrees into the application space.
>
> SQLAlchemy commonly refers to an
>   adjacency list relationship as a
>   self-referential mapper. In this
>   example, we’ll work with a single
>   table called treenodes to represent a
>   tree structure:

A graph such as the following:

```
root --+---> child1
       +---> child2 --+--> subchild1
       |              +--> subchild2
       +---> child3
```

Would be represented with data such as:

```
id       parent_id     data
---      -------       ----
1        NULL          root
2        1             child1
3        1             child2
4        3             subchild1
5        3             subchild2
6        1             child3
```

Answer (score 0):

Following OMG Ponies's comment, and http://sqllessons.com/categories.html,
perhaps try something like this:

```
select 
       MAN1.RX as MAN1_RX,
       MAN1.RY as MAN1_RY,
       MAN1.RZ  as MAN1_RZ,
       MAN2.RX as MAN2_RX,
       MAN2.RY as MAN2_RY,
       MAN2.RZ  as MAN2_RZ,
       MAN3.RX as MAN3_RX,
       MAN3.RY as MAN3_RY,
       MAN3.RZ  as MAN3_RZ,
  from table as MAN1
left outer
  join table as MAN2
    on MAN1.NEXT = MAN2.Id
left outer
  join table as MAN3
    on MAN3.NEXT = MAN2.Id
where MAN1.Id = 'MAN1'
```

PS. I'm not terribly familiar with sqlite, but assuming it does not have direct hierarchical query syntax, then this link (http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/1638233-equivalent-start-connect-mysql.html) points to the above work-around.